# Eclipse dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project which is a XML parser and is static meaning it reads the XML and caches its contents. I have multiple EJB projects which reference to this java project so that it can use the cached parsed content from the XML. 
How do I add this as a dependency to all other projects using this so that if there is a change to the XML class, I should change and deploy this once and all other projects referencing this should starting seeing the change?

Answer (score 0):

Look into provisioning tools. One of the most common ones for Java is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Using maven, you can accomplish your desired behaviour.